# proper way of catching control+key in ncurses

Tags: ncurses

What is the proper way of catching a control+key in ncurses?
current im doing it defining control like this:

```
#define ctl(x) ((x) & 0x1f)
```

it works ok, but the problem is that i cannot catch C-j and ENTER at the same time, and this is because:

```
   j = 106 = 1101010
0x1f = 31 = 0011111
1101010 & 0011111 = 0001010 = 10 = ENTER key..
```

So.. how shall I catch it?
Thanks!

--
Edit:
If i try the code below,
I am not able to catch the enter key correctly, not even in the numeric keyboard. Enter gets catched as ctrl-j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#define ctrl(x) ((x) & 0x1f)

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    int c = getch();
    nonl();
    switch (c) {
        case KEY_ENTER:
            printw("key: %c", c);
            break;
        case ctrl('j'):
            printw("key: ctrl j");
            break;
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
    return;
}
```

New code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#define ctrl(x)           ((x) & 0x1f)

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    int l = -1;
    int c = getch();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nonl();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    switch (c) {
        case KEY_ENTER:
            printw("key: %c", c);
            break;
        case ctrl('j'):
            printw("key: ctrl j");
            break;
    }
    printw("\nnow press a key to end");
    getch();
    endwin();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`nonl`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-nl_-nonl):

> The **`nl`** and **`nonl`** routines control whether the underlying display  device
>          translates  the return key into newline on input, and whether it translates newline into return and line-feed on output (in either case,  the
>          **`call addch('\n')`**  does  the  equivalent of return and line feed on the
>          virtual screen).  Initially, these translations do occur.  If you  disable  them  using  nonl,  curses will be able to make better use of the
>          line-feed capability, resulting in faster cursor motion.  Also,  curses
>          will then be able to detect the return key.

Further reading: the [Notes section](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h2-NOTES) of the `getch` manual page:

> Generally,  KEY_ENTER denotes the character(s) sent by the Enter key on
>          the numeric keypad:
>
> - the terminal description lists the most useful keys,
> - the Enter key on the regular keyboard is  already  handled  by  the
>            standard ASCII characters for carriage-return and line-feed,
> - depending on whether nl or nonl was called, pressing "Enter" on the
>            regular keyboard may return either a carriage-return or  line-feed,
>            and finally
> - "Enter or send" is the standard description for this key.

That addresses the question about newline/carriage-return translation.  A followup comment is a reminder to point out that the manual page gives basic advice in the [Initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) section:

> To get character-at-a-time input  without  echoing  (most  interactive,
>          screen  oriented  programs want this), the following sequence should be
>          used:

```
     initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
```

and that OP's sample program did not use `cbreak` (or `raw`).  The manual page for [`cbreak`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak) says

> Normally, the tty driver buffers typed characters until  a  newline  or
>          carriage  return  is typed.  The **`cbreak`** routine disables line buffering
>          and erase/kill character-processing (interrupt and flow control characters  are  unaffected), making characters typed by the user immediately
>          available to the program.  The **`nocbreak`** routine returns the terminal to
>          normal (cooked) mode.
>
> Initially the terminal may or may not be in cbreak mode, as the mode is
>          inherited; therefore, a program should call **`cbreak`** or **`nocbreak`**  explicitly.   *Most  interactive  programs  using  curses set the cbreak mode*.
>   Note that **`cbreak`** overrides **`raw`**.  (See [curs_getch(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) for  a  discussion
>   of how these routines interact with **`echo`** and **`noecho`**.)

Also, in [`curs_getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Keypad-mode) you may read

> If [**`keypad`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) is TRUE, and a function key is pressed, the  token  for  that
>   function key is returned instead of the raw characters:
>
> - The  predefined  function  keys  are listed in `<curses.h>` as macros
>            with values outside the range of 8-bit characters.  Their names begin with **`KEY_`**.

That is, curses will only return `KEY_ENTER` if the program calls `keypad`:

```
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

For the sake of discussion, here is an example fixing some of the problems with your sample program as of May 17:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#define ctrl(x)           ((x) & 0x1f)

int
main(void)
{
    int c;
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nonl();
    c = getch();
    switch (c) {
    case KEY_ENTER:
        printw("\nkey_enter: %d", c);
        break;
    case ctrl('j'):
        printw("\nkey: ctrl j");
        break;
    default:
        printw("\nkeyname: %d = %s\n", c, keyname(c));
        break;
    }
    printw("\nnow press a key to end");
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

That is, you have to call `keypad` before `getch`, and the value returned for **`KEY_ENTER`** is not a character (it cannot be printed with `%c`).

Running on the Linux console with the usual terminal description, you will see only carriage return for the numeric keypad <kbd>*Enter*</kbd>, because that description does not use *application mode*.  Linux console does support application mode, and a corresponding description could be written.  As a quick check (there are differences...) you could set `TERM=vt100` to see the **`KEY_ENTER`**.

Comment: if i set nonl, then I can no longer catch enter key. I am catching it with KEY_ENTER macro of ncurses.h.. EDIT: is the way i define ctrl macro correct?

Comment: Edited again, adding a new example program using keypad, cbreak and noecho. same results: ENTER is caught as C-j..

Comment: My bad. If I change it to TRUE, I got the same result. Enter is caught as C-j.

Comment: You didn't mention (a) **`TERM`** or (b) the actual terminal (emulator).  Given that, one might point out the problem.

Comment: /sbin/agetty, TERM=linux. It also happens in tmux. I updated the second example code.

Comment: I managed to get the ENTER and C-j separately, getting the first one as keyname: 13 = ^M with your example code. But I cant get it with KEY_ENTER, doesnt matter if I set TERM to vt100..