# How do I capture "CTRL + ARROW_KEY" with PD/NCurses?

Tags: ncurses, pdcurses

While I figured out that I can just use something like [`#define ctrl(x) ((x) & 0x1f)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924525/11465149)<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960443/11465149)</sup> for most plain ASCII *(non numerical or [obviously] symbol)* characters, I was unable to find any info or documentation on how to capture `CTRL + ARROW_KEYS` or any other sane\logical combinations of `CTRL + SHIFT + ch`  and so on...

The reason I care about this, is because I am trying to maintain a project called [`unicurses`](https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses) and while I'm trying to maintain this project I'm also making a [prototype demo of a terminal based editor](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11987271/144284903-19bb6dbc-aef4-4d52-95f4-aa688481eb39.gif) with it where I need to capture those kind of key combinations and so I was looking for some help *(also I really don't care if the answer will be in c\c++, python or whatever, I'm just looking for a way of doing it)*

Any Idea?

Comment: *(I know it sounds kinda silly but)* I might have found a work around using a second `get_wch` in a row, I might test it when I get back to my PC

Comment: ^ It was just silly, nvm..

Answer (score 3):

Try the "Input Test" in PDCurses' `testcurs` demo. You'll see there that CTRL + Up Arrow is returned as "CTL_UP". The full list of named keys is in curses.h. Some combinations can only be distinguished by their modifiers, as returned by `PDC_get_key_modifiers()`.

I'm not sure how or whether you'd do it in ncurses.

In general, I recommend you avoid these exotic key combos.

Comment: Thanks! i'll check it out

Comment: regarding ncurses, that's an [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#modified_keys).